# How do I utilize disk space in batch?

Tags: windows-xp, batch

I'm trying to write a batch file that would kinda go like this:

```
if DiskSpace > 255MB for C:, goto 1
:1
copy "E:\file.txt" "C:\destination\"
```

It's for a program I assembled, and I needed to create an installer for my employees.

Is this possible? If my description is too vague, I'll explain a bit more:

I'm trying to get a batch file to do certain commands depending on how much free space is available on the C: drive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. The OS is XP.

P.S.S I would also like everything to be in one batch script file, preferably not multiple files.

Comment: Ancient!  XP is long out of support, and modern Windows has Powershell for this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plain old batch file for this is going to prove tedious and cumbersome.  Instead consider doing your script in something like VBscript (included in XP) or Powershell (*probably* would require installation).  Rough VBscript example:

```
Dim fso, drv

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set drv = fso.GetDrive("C:")

IF drv.FreeSpace / (1024 *1024) > 255 Then
     '
     '  Do some useful stuff here
     '
     wscript.echo drv.FreeSpace / (1024 * 1024) 
End If
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8(v=vs.84).aspx for some examples of 'useful stuff' (such as the Copy, Move and Delete methods).

Comment: Thank you, Brandon. This is the answer I was looking for!